Transition maps for a vector bundle $V$ given a s.e.s $0\longrightarrow L_1 \longrightarrow V \longrightarrow L_2 \longrightarrow 0$
Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be line bundles over say a compact smooth manifold $M$. If we have a vector bundle $V$ such that
$$
0\longrightarrow L_1 \longrightarrow V \longrightarrow L_2 \longrightarrow 0
$$
is exact, is it so that the transition maps for $V$ are given by an upper triangular matrix? I do know that the direct sum of vector bundles has transition functions given by a block diagonal matrix, but I don't see how this thing has transition maps given by an upper triangular matrix.

What are the linear maps $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ that preserve the $x_1$-axis?

If $V$ is complex vector bundle then you can always use the Jordan form to triangularize the transition maps. Moreover, you do not need to have a subbundle of rank $1$.

@AlessandroFrassineti Why should Jordan form have anything to do with the distinguished subbundle?

Nothing, that's what I meant. You can always suppose that the matrixes are upper triangular.

Oh, so OP should be more specific about the intended meaning of the diagonal entries (blocks) of the upper-triangular matrix, of course. These are respectively the transition functions of $L_i$.

Yes I was after the blocks being the transition functions for $L_i$'s. The linear maps preserving $x_1$-axis are the upper triangular ones. @TedShifrin

So why does that not answer you question? :)

Whether the transition maps for $V$ are upper triangular will depend on your choice of local bases for $V$. Fortunately, there's an easy way to get a basis: Use a (local) basis for $L_1$ as the first basis vector, and lift to  $V$ a (local) basis for $L_2$ as the second. There's an arbitrary choice, in lifting from $L_2$ to $V$, but no matter how you make that choice, you'll get a triangular matrix.
